# VS Code showing 'unknown' in place of user/path in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is my first question on stack overflow so apologies if anything is incorrectly formatted.

Whenever I open the terminal in VS Code it presents 'unknown' as the path/user (not exactly sure what it is):

[image: screenshot of terminal in visual studio code]

It is not specific to node or bash. As far as I know this isn't actually causing any issues with my code.

I don't have this issue in my mac terminal.

I have looked online for answers and couldn't find anything appropriate, but could be that I don't know how to phrase the question correctly.

Thanks! Let me know if you need any more info.